# how to model this mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

[image]

How to model this mesh? I tried wireframe modifier, but it is not good. i tried but didn't find a way to make it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Hmm, the mesh part should be easy: get a grid, use poke faces to get diagonals, then delete the cardinal vertices (or just dissolve for now. The tricky part is getting it folded up like that. Cloth simulation might work, but be VERY gentle so as to avoid intersection. Then try the wireframe modifier.

Comment: I'd recommend modelling it as a solid mesh without the gaps, and using an opacity map to create the holes

Comment: @ James, alpha transparency would be very convenient but it doesn't have thickness